# Spring Cloud Config Server Could not resolve placeholder

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker-compose, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have added spring-cloud-config-server to my stack in the hope of having different sets of config loaded for different spring profiles (namely development, staging and production).

My config server app starts on port 8888, fetches config directly from a private gitlab repository and has security. I tested this by hitting it manually and checking that the correct properties are returning. So far so good.

I will have several 'client' apps that I want to consume the properties from my config server but for now I'm just trying with one. To test it out, I've put a

```
@Value("${some.property}")
private string someProperty;
```

in one of my web resources in the client app. This property is not in any of the client app's property files (wondering if this may be the issue - but it seems restrictive if it is).

I've also pointed the client app at the config server. The config for both apps both config server and client app are in their bootstrap.properties files to ensure they're loaded early in the process.

In fact my two apps are containerised in Docker images and they are brought up by a docker-compose.yml file. I've actually got it set up to that the client app waits for the config server to be running before starting up.

During the client app's startup, I can see it fetching config from the config server:

```
| 20:12:50.692 [main] INFO  o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.getRemoteEnvironment 205 - Fetching config from server at : http://config-server:8888
```

and it appears to be successful with a 205.

However, the client app startup then fails:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'exampleResource': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'some.property' in value "${some.property}"
```

I have the active profile set to 'development' in the client app. The properties files on the config server are named:

```
myapp-development.properties
myapp-staging.properties
myapp-production.properties
```

My hope is of course that the client app fetches the config from the server (which I can see happen) and then that property is available to the client app as it starts up but this does not appear to be the case. Is it as simple as specifying a default in the value annotation? Or am I overlooking something more fundamental? I followed this guide fwiw and my config server is pointing to a git repository as I mentioned above:

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-configuration

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Fetching config from server at ..." log is happening before getting the data not after and 205 - it's not a response code. (have no idea what is this, check you logger format). After this log message in general you should see 'Located environment...' and then 'Located property source...' with information about properties. In general your assumptions and understanding are correct and you don't need any default values. Looks like It should be smth simple and overlooked. Could you please provide src code in github (can be everything in one repo)? And I will try to resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks.. so that output is no guarantee of fetching the config then.. I see. OK I can't share the whole code base but I shoved the (hopefully) relevant bits in some gists.... Config service: https://gist.github.com/bbk-pij-2012-22/acf2772969d27e83134351557c1bf011 Client service: https://gist.github.com/bbk-pij-2012-22/075dcb33ca8edb21d77ab87c24cccd2d Resource with the rogue variable (just for testing purposes and clearly we don't even get this far): https://gist.github.com/bbk-pij-2012-22/f7338bac24c6156602716cdf665028df  Please ask for anything specific. Sorry for delay! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Oh and the 3 properties files I mentioned in the original question all contain just that 1 property (some.property). What am I doing wrong! : >

Comment: Answered. If you didn't invent other names for test sharing sources - the root cause is in the client app name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set credentials incorrectly in the client side app.

It should be

```
spring.cloud.config.username=myConfigServerUserName
spring.cloud.config.password=myConfigServerPassword
```

instead of `spring.security.user.name` and `spring.security.user.password` (which are used in the config server app).

See:
http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/2.0.1.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_security_2

Comment: As you mentioned above, you're quite right - I did invent names to obscure them but I made a mistake in the gist. The name of the client app = the 'myapp' part of myapp-development.properties. I called it myClientApp just to make it clear that it was the client consuming the config. It has a one word name (myapp for argument's sake) and it matches the first part of the property file names....

Comment: @DaisyDay I've edited the answer, hope this time I resolved your issue :)

Comment: You're a legend. Thank you. Stupid oversight on my part! All working as expected now. Thanks again :))